# Отправляемые данные ajax post запросом

Tags: c#, html, ajax, asp.net-mvc

Есть модель. С формы отправляется ajax запросом несколько полей с такими же названиями как и у свойств модели. Но в модели есть свойство Picture типа string куда пишеться base64 представление изображения. Но такая проблема что я использую ajax begin form. Если с помощью jquery я могу отдельно помимо формы отправить ещё параметры, то тут уже не знаю как этого сделать. Подскажите пожалуйста как с использованием ajax.beginform отправить base64 код который находится в элементе img src. Хотел назвать img так же как свойство модели, но у img нет атрибута name. Подскажите как можно решить мою задачу?

Comment: `<input type="hidden" name="..." value="..." />`

Comment: @Igor и в это поле записать base64 код такой же который лежит в src?

Comment: совершенно верно - в `value`

Comment: @Igor большое спасибо, хорошая идея